# How to replace a digit in a string of numbers with a random number

Tags: string, matlab, random

I have a string which is a sequence of numbers between 0-9, I would like to replace some of the numbers in that string with random numbers, but I'm unable to do with with either `rand` or `randi` as I keep getting the following error:

```
Conversion to char from cell is not possible.

Error in work (line 58)
                mut(i,7:14) = {mute_by};
```

Here's what I'm currently doing to try and alter some digits of my string:

```
    % mutate probability 0.2
        if (rand < 0.2)
            % pick best chromosome to mutate
            mut = combo{10};
            mute_by = rand([0,9]);
            for i = 1:5
                mut(i) = {mute_by};
            end
        end
```

`mut` represents the string `110202132224154246176368198100`

How would I go about doing this? I assumed it would be fairly simple but I've been going over the documentation for a while now and I can't find the solution.

Comment: So you have a string such as `110202132224154246176368198100` and want to change 20% of those values. 1) Do you mean exactly 20% of each string, or change each number with 20% probability (so that the proportion will be 20% only on average)? 2) Each random new number should be uniformly distributed from 0 to 9?

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is generate a `logical` array that represents `true` if you want to replace a particular position in your string and `false` otherwise.  How you're determining this is by generating random floating pointing point numbers of the same size as your string, and checking to see if their values are `< 0.2`.  For any positions in your string that satisfy this constraint, replace them with another random integer.

The best way to do this would be to convert your string into actual numbers so that you can actual modify their positions numerically, create our `logical` array, then replace these values with random integers at these co-ordinates.

Something like this:

```
rng(123); %// Set seed for reproducibility
mut = '110202132224154246176368198100';
mut_num = double(mut) - 48;
n = numel(mut_num);
vec = rand(1, n) < 0.4;
num_elem = sum(vec);
mut_num(vec) = randi(10,1,num_elem) - 1;
mut_final = char(mut_num + 48);
```

Let's go through this code slowly. [`rng`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html) is a random seed generator, and I set it to `123` so that you're able to reproduce the same results that I have made as random number generation... is of course random.  I declare the number you have made as a `string`, then I have a nifty trick of turning each character in your string into a single element of a numeric array.  I do this by casting to `double`, then subtracting by 48.  By casting to `double`, each element gets converted into its [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/), and so `0` would be 48, `1` would be 49 and so on.  Therefore, we need to **subtract** the values by 48 so that we can bring this down to a range of `[0-9]`.  I then count how long your string is with [`numel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html), then figure out which values I want to replace by generating that `logical` vector we talked about.

We then count up how many elements we need to change, then generate a random integer vector that is **exactly** this size, and we use this `logical` vector to index into our recently converted string (being stored as a numeric array) with random integers.  Note that `randi` generates values from 1 up to whatever maximum you want.  Because this starts at 1, I have to generate up to 10, then **subtract** by 1.  The output of `randi` gets placed into our numeric array, and then we convert our numeric array into a string with `char`.  Note that we need to **add** by 48 to convert the numbers into their ASCII equivalents before creating our string.

I've changed the probability to 0.4 to actually see the changes better.  Setting this to `0.2` I could barely notice any changes.  `mut_final` would contain the changed string.  Here is what they look like:

```
>> mut

mut =

110202132224154246176368198100

>> vec

vec =

  Columns 1 through 13

     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0

  Columns 14 through 26

     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1

  Columns 27 through 30

     1     1     1     0

>> mut_final

mut_final =

104202132444143248176368195610
```

---

`vec` contains those positions in the string you want to change, starting from the 2nd position, 3rd position, etc.  The corresponding positions in `mut` change with respect to `vec` while the rest of the string is untouched and is finally stored in `mut_final`.

Comment: This is more or less what I was typing :-) You don't need to convert the whole vector with -48 / +48 ; just add 48 to the new entries